# TOR & CURL PHP: Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (1)

Tags: php, tor, php-curl

Я уже задавал этот вопрос, но так как писал в спешке и о многом не написал, решил удалить его и создать новый, указав все подробности.

Есть сайт, который делает запросы к onion-сайту в TOR. Его посещают примерно 200 пользователей в день.

Иногда появляются curl-ошибки:

> Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (1)

> Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (5)

Я так и не выяснил закономерность этих ошибок. Они появляются часто, но **не всегда**.

```
$url = 'http://site.onion'.str_replace(array('&'), array('%26'), trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); 

$headers = array(
 // Здесь все верные заголовки, включая User-Agent TOR
);   

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:9050');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);

$curl_error = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if($curl_error) {
 echo $curl_error;
 print_r($curl_info);
} else {
 echo $response;
}
```

curl_getinfo($ch):

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://site.onion/images/uploads/4tR43Zr43x.jpg
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.000207
    [namelookup_time] => 7.8E-5
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
```

Я пытаюсь решить эту проблему уже несколько дней и до сих пор не могу. Время на моём сервере установлено правильно. CURL версия 7.58.0

Comment: по моему в том вопросе вам писали про возможные проблемы с прокси. Прокси у вас в соединении есть.

Comment: @ArchDemon, ну если смотреть на сам тор, то он достаточно стабильно работает.

Comment: Я работаю с различными публичными API. Отваливаются даже самые надёжные. Иногда не по их вине, а вине моего провайдера. Или их провайдера.